# Vbscript randomize with step

Tags: random, vbscript

How to get random number in range (0,123) with step (5)

Do get random number in range (0,123) i do

```
Dim max,min
max=123
min=0
Randomize
response.write(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
```

But i need only steped 5 (0,5,10,15,20,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function StepRandom( ByVal minValue, ByVal maxValue, ByVal Steps )
    maxValue = maxValue - maxValue Mod Steps
    Randomize
    StepRandom = maxValue-Fix((maxValue - minValue + 1)*Rnd/Steps)*Steps
End Function 

Response.Write CStr(StepRandom(0,120,5))
```

The basic operation is to adjust the max value to the correct step point and from this max value down calculate a step point in the indicated range

Answer (score 1):

I would, first, get the real min and max :

```
If min Mod 5 > 0 Then
  min = min + (5 - (min Mod 5))
End If
max = max - (max Mod 5)
```

Then, get a random number between 0 and (max-min) / 5, multiply it by 5, and add min.

```
Dim number
number = Int(((((max - min) / 5) + 1) * Rnd) * 5 + min)
```